# Параллельная обработка данных в TransformStream (Web Streams API)

Tags: javascript, многопоточность, потоки-данных, parallelstream

Уже достаточно давно в браузерах доступно экспериментальное **[Web Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API)**, отдаленно похожее на *Stream* в *Node.js*.

Стандарт всё ещё сырой, несмотря на то что пилится не один год, но выглядит весьма перспективно. Разрабатывается и продвигается видимо не *Mozilla*, а скорее *Google*, т.к. все компоненты поддерживаются только в его движке. Нашел актуальный [web-streams-polyfill](https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill) для всех браузеров с *IE11*, реализованный по официальному [Official spec](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/). Впрочем и стандарт и реализация несколько запутаны, с моей точки зрения.

Имея небольшой опыт работы с *Node.js stream* я хотел перенести его на *браузерный JavaScript*. Однако столкнулся с препятствием в различиях реализации и отсутствием пакетов поверх стандарта. С кривым и сырым стандартом как-то смирился, хотя хотелось бы найти пакет портирования *Node.js stream* для браузера. Однако без пакетов поверх стандарта совсем кисло. Да ещё и информации по технологии, помимо официальной документации, как кот наплакал.

**Вопрос**: Как на *Web Streams API* реализовать параллельную обработку фрагментов потока?

По всей видимости, согласно задумки афторов технологии, обработка и преобразование данных должна осуществляться **[TransformStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransformStream)**. Проблема в том, что все описание и примеры построены так что преобразование осуществляется синхронно. Да, методы ***pull*** (у *ReadableStream*) и ***transform*** (у *TransformStream*) поддерживают возврат ***Promise***, но в этом случае следующий фрагмент не генерируется (или не запрашивается для трансформации), до разрешения обещания... Например:

```js
var streamR = new ReadableStream({
  start: (controller)=>{
    this.counterR = 0;
  },
  pull: (controller)=> new Promise((resolve)=> setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve();
    if ( this.counterR++ >= 5 ) return controller.close();
    controller.enqueue( new Date );
  }, Math.random() * 500 ) )
});

var streamT1 = new TransformStream({
  start: (controller)=>{
  },
  transform: ( chunk, controller )=> new Promise( ( resolve )=> setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve();
    controller.enqueue( 'T1: ' + chunk );
  }, Math.random() * 500 ) )
});

var streamPT1 = streamR.pipeThrough( streamT1 );
var streamW = new WritableStream({
  start: ()=>{ this.counterW = 0; },
  write: (data)=>{ console.log( ++this.counterW, this.counterR, 'Write:', data );
} });
var promise = streamPT1.pipeTo( streamW );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web-streams-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Я хочу использовать потоки для обработки массива данных. Если генерировать данные для потока я могу каким угодно способом, то трансформировать (аки обсчитывать)... как бы не любым. А хочется отдать их на обработку в [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Worker).

Для *Worker* уже написан менеджер фоновых заданий на основе [WorkCrew](https://gist.github.com/kig/1188381) и модуль, куда вынесены все самые тяжелые вычисления. *WorkCrew* создаёт пул *Worker* по числу потоков процессора (см. [core-estimator](https://github.com/oftn-oswg/core-estimator)), т.к. если у клиента будет 4х поточный процессор, то будет создано столько же *Worker*, а значит столько может выполняться одновременно фоновых заданий...

Подскажи как в **TransformStream** забрать нужное число фрагментов из входного потока для одновременной обработки, а по готовности любого из взятых положить результат трансформации в выходной и взять следующий фрагмент на освободившееся место?..

Я хочу обсчитать массив данных, причем порядок обсчета не важен, а важна скорость... Когда весь массив будет обсчитан (отслеживается через обещание от *pipeTo*), то запустится уже другая обработка.

***PS*** Можно реализовать весь расчет без *stream*, что уже не сделано, но хочется навести порядок и привести все промежуточные функции к одной схеме для удобной поддержки и повторного использования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После ещё несколько раз прочтения [спецификации](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/), изучения исходников [Reference implementation](https://github.com/whatwg/streams) и [web-streams-polyfill](https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill), а так же плотного обеда пришел к выводу что спать нужно нормально, тогда и глупых вопросов возникать не будет, ибо решение лежало в одном из [примеров](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/streams/png-transform-stream/) на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API).

Т.е. можно легко реализовать *Parallel Transform* на коробочном *TransformStream* (хотя обёртка всё же не помешала бы):

```js
var time = ()=> Math.random() * 1000;

// эмулятор менеджера фоновых заданий
var job = new (function(){
  this.limit = 4;
  this._buffer = [];
  this._callback = null;
  this.push = (chunk)=>{ this._buffer.push(chunk); };
  this.on = (fn)=>{ this._callback = fn; };
  this.close = ()=>{ clearTimeout( this._timer ); this._buffer = null; };
  this.size = ()=> this._buffer.length;
  let pos;
  let count = 0;
  const loop = ()=>{
    if ( this._callback && this._buffer && this._buffer.length > 0 ) {
      pos = Math.floor( Math.random() * this._buffer.length );
      this._callback( '[Трансформация №' + ++count + ' по порядку обработки]  <= ' + this._buffer.splice( pos, 1 )[0] );
    }
    this._timer = setTimeout( loop, time() );
  };
  this._timer = setTimeout( loop, time() );
})();

var streamR = new ReadableStream({
  start: function ( controller ) {
    // счетчик фрагментов/задач
    this.counterR = 0;
  },
  pull: function ( controller ) {
    const self = this;
    // генерация задач, с небольшой задержкой
    return new Promise( ( resolve )=>
      setTimeout( ()=>{
        resolve();
        // закрываем поток после 10 фрагментов/задач
        if ( self.counterR++ >= 10 ) {
          return controller.close();
        }
        // помещение фрагмента/задачи в поток
        controller.enqueue( '[Задача №' + self.counterR + ']' );
      })
    )
  }
});

var streamT1 = new TransformStream({
  start: function ( controller ) {
    const self = this;
    this.counterT = 0;
    this.countWotkers = 4;
    // эмулятор асинхронной фоновой обработки (аки Worker) - порядок не сохраняется
    job.on( (chunk)=> {
        controller.enqueue( chunk );
    } );
  },
  transform: function ( chunk /*,controller*/ ) {
    const self = this;
    // асинхронная обработка фрагментов/заданий
    return new Promise( ( resolve )=> setTimeout( function loop() {
      // наполнение буфера фрагментов/задач, пока в нем есть место
      if ( job.size() < job.limit ) {
        job.push( chunk );
        return resolve();
      }
      // эмуляция затрат времени на передачу данных в Worker
      setTimeout( loop, time() );
    }) )
  },
  flush: function ( /*controller*/ ) {
    // ожидание завершения всех асинхронных фоновых работ перед объявлением завершения трансформации
    return new Promise( ( resolve )=> {
      const timer = setInterval( ()=> {
        if ( !job.size() ) {
          clearInterval( timer );
          job.close();
          resolve();
        }
      });
    })
  }
});

var streamPT1 = streamR.pipeThrough( streamT1 );
var streamW = new WritableStream( {
  start: function () {
    this.counterW = 0;
  },
  write: function (data) {
    console.log( 'Write', ++this.counterW, ' <= ', data );
  }
});
var promise = streamPT1.pipeTo( streamW ).then( ()=> console.log( 'ok' ) ).catch( ()=> console.log( 'error' ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web-streams-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Надеюсь, это будет полезно тем кто ищет способ ускорить обработку данных в браузере... При использовании потоков нет необходимости в дополнительном буфере или организации очереди и связей шагов алгоритма - говорим шаги алгоритма, а как он будут выполнен скрывается потоком. Кроме того появляется возможность в любой момент отследить прогресс выполнения, да и просто сосредоточится на общем алгоритме, не вдаваясь в детали.

Возможно кто-то сможет меня поправить или предложить другое решение, если я ошибся.